# wpf Listview How to make sub text

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a list view populated with items, some of these items have a second line associated with them.

I would like to know if there is a way that i can style that second line so it could be a smaller font, or even change the color of it.

This is how i am currently adding things to the listview.

```
listview.Items.Add(New With {Key .name = "First Line" & vbNewLine & "Second Line", .path = path})
```

My Listview XAML

```
<ListView Background="transparent" Margin="10 10 10 10" x:Name="listview" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="name" Width="790" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="path" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
```

Here is a picture of what i have at the moment so you can see what i am talking about.
[image]

Comment: instead of using linebreak, you should define a new property in your item `subname`, and then you can customize the style of `ItemTemplate` to display different style for `subname`. [Here is a tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1).

Comment: You can use runs but it would be easier with a template as suggested by Bolu

Comment: I have updated my question. How would i implement the itemtemplate with my current xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making a class for the bound data.  Populate the class with information and add to the `Items` property.

The other commenters on this thread suggest using a template.  For your situation, the `CellTemplate` is probably the best choice.

**XAML**

```
<ListView Background="transparent"
      Margin="10 10 10 10"
      x:Name="listview"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalContentAlignment="center"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      BorderBrush="Transparent">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="name"
                      Width="400"   >
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="25"
                               Text="{Binding FirstLine}" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Foreground='Orange'
                   Text="{Binding SecondLine}" />
          </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="path"   
                        Width="200" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}" />
        </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

**Code**

```
 Class MainWindow
   Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
     For index = 1 To 5
       listview.Items.Add(New BoundDocument With {.FirstLine = index.ToString("D2") & " First Line",
                                                  .SecondLine = "Second Line --" & index.ToString("D2"),
                                                  .Path = "Path " & index})

    Next
 End Sub
End Class

Public Class BoundDocument
    Public Property FirstLine As String
    Public Property SecondLine As String
    Public Property Path As String

End Class
```

**Screenshot**
[image]